# Find count of all points in a 3d space that are strictly less than any of the points in that space?

Tags: algorithm, 3d

We are given n points in a 3d space ,we need to find count of all points that are strictly less than atleast one of the points in the 3d space
i.e.

```
x1<x2 and y1<y2  and z1<z2
```

so (x1,y1,z1) would be one such point.

```
For example,Given points

1 4 2
4 3 2
2 5 3


(1,4,2)<(2,5,3)

So the answer for the above case should be the count of such points i.e. 1.
```

I know this can be solved through a O(n^2) algorithm but i need something faster,i tried sorting through one dimension and then searching only over the greater part of the key , but its still o(n^2) worst case.

What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "less"? Is `(1,5,2) < (2,4,2)` ? Do you mean, closest to the origin, as in `d^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2` and comparing distance `d`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to optimize your search that may be faster than `O(n^2)` - I would welcome counter-sample input.

Keep three lists of the indexes of the points, sorted by x, y and z respectively. Make a fourth list associating each point with it's place in each of the lists (`indexes` in the code below; e. g., `indexes[0] = [5,124,789]` would mean the first point is 5th in the x-sorted list, 124th in the y-sorted list, and 789th in the z-sorted list).

Now iterate over the points - pick the list where the point is highest and test the point against the higher indexed points in the list, exiting early if the point is strictly less than one of them. If a point is low on all three lists, the likelihood of finding a strictly higher point is greater. Otherwise, a higher place in one of the lists means less iterations.

JavaScript code:

```js
function strictlyLessThan(p1,p2){
  return p1[0] < p2[0] && p1[1] < p2[1] && p1[2] < p2[2];
}

// iterations
var it = 0;

function f(ps){
  var res = 0,
      indexes = new Array(ps.length);
  
  // sort by x
  var sortedX = 
        ps.map(function(x,i){ return i; })
          .sort(function(a,b){ return ps[a][0] - ps[b][0]; });
  
  // record index of point in x-sorted list
  for (var i=0; i<sortedX.length; i++){
    indexes[sortedX[i]] = [i,null,null];
  }
  
  // sort by y
  var sortedY = 
        ps.map(function(x,i){ return i; })
          .sort(function(a,b){ return ps[a][1] - ps[b][1]; });
  
  // record index of point in y-sorted list
  for (var i=0; i<sortedY.length; i++){
    indexes[sortedY[i]][1] = i;
  }
  
  // sort by z
  var sortedZ = 
        ps.map(function(x,i){ return i; })
          .sort(function(a,b){ return ps[a][2] - ps[b][2]; });
  
  // record index of point in z-sorted list
  for (var i=0; i<sortedZ.length; i++){
    indexes[sortedZ[i]][2] = i;
  }
  
  // check for possible greater points only in the list
  // where the point is highest
  for (var i=0; i<ps.length; i++){
    var listToCheck,
        startIndex;
    
    if (indexes[i][0] > indexes[i][1]){
      if (indexes[i][0] > indexes[i][2]){
        listToCheck = sortedX;
        startIndex = indexes[i][0];
      } else {
        listToCheck = sortedZ;
        startIndex = indexes[i][2];
      }
      
    } else {
      if (indexes[i][1] > indexes[i][2]){
        listToCheck = sortedY;
        startIndex = indexes[i][1];
      } else {
        listToCheck = sortedZ;
        startIndex = indexes[i][2];
      }
    }
    
    var j = startIndex + 1;
 
    while (listToCheck[j] !== undefined){
      it++;
      var point = ps[listToCheck[j]];
 
      if (strictlyLessThan(ps[i],point)){
        res++;
        break;
      }
      j++;
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

// var input = [[5,0,0],[4,1,0],[3,2,0],[2,3,0],[1,4,0],[0,5,0],[4,0,1],[3,1,1], [2,2,1],[1,3,1],[0,4,1],[3,0,2],[2,1,2],[1,2,2],[0,3,2],[2,0,3], [1,1,3],[0,2,3],[1,0,4],[0,1,4],[0,0,5]];

var input = new Array(10000);

for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  input[i] = [Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()];
}

console.log(input.length + ' points');
console.log('result: ' + f(input));
console.log(it + ' iterations not including sorts');
```

Comment: This makes around 5,750,000 calls to StrictlyLessThan() for 1,000,000 random points; and you have to do the sorting first. It's better than NxN, but less efficient than the list-of-greatest-points method. (I added my test code for comparison)

Comment: But if you use `var x = Math.random(), y = Math.random(), z = 2 - x - y; input[i] = [x,y,z];` it makes both our algorithms cry :-)

Comment: Yes, my idea seems less efficient than your method. I was hoping it might cover more variable input but couldn't come up with enough examples to think it through. Thanks for the counter example - if you know, could you say a few words about why the counter example works?

Comment: It's basically using the equation x+y+z=n that defines a plane where no point is xyz-less than any other point (see my answer). That type of input is why the worst-case complexity will always be NxN; you have to check every point against every other point, only to find that it isn't xyz-less than anything. In my algorithm, this means every point is added to the list. The OP seems to be hoping to reduce the worst-case complexity, but I'm convinced that it's impossible.

Comment: @m69 But why would it work against my algo as well? I'm getting around 4,700,000 iterations for 5000 points with the `z = 2 - x - y` method (I don't include sorts in the iteration count since that complexity is known). I'm not sure if it's an order of magnitude, but it's less than 25 mil.

Comment: The points that are high in one list will be low in another list (because x+y+z is the same for every point) so they can never be quickly discarded without a lot of comparisons. But the fact that you get less than 5 mil iterations isn't bad; my algorithm needs the full 25 mil for 5000 worst-case points, so my average-case complexity is better but your worst-case complexity is better. But it's better by a factor of 5, which isn't much help if you want to run the worst-case with 1,000,000 points.

Comment: Actually, it may be the points that are in the middle of the three lists that may be the problem; I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @m69 being high in one list is what my algorithm counts on since it only iterates up from the highest position in the list where it's highest. But I'm curious why that method creates a significant enough pool of points that are in the middle. I also realize now that exiting early never gets applied since it can't find a strictly greater partner.

Comment: Indeed, the efficiency of any algorithm is based on "xyz-less" being transitive. If you find that a<b, you can discard a and only check other points against b, because if c<a then c<b. Your algorithm gets quicker answers for points at the extremes of the lists, but for worst-case input the answer is always that you can't discard the point, which doesn't reduce the number of comparisons for the next point. So the ordering into 3 lists reduces the number of comparisons from 25mil to 5mil, but discarding points in random input reduces it from 5mil to 25,000, which makes the real difference.

Comment: @m69 are you're saying there's a way to reduce comparisons for 5000 points of your `z = 2 - x - y` example to 25,000? How?

Comment: No, I mean that the factor 1000 you get with 5000 random points (25k instead of 25M iterations) consists of a factor 5 because of the sorting into three lists, and a factor 200 because most of the points can be discarded. When you then run it on 5000 worst-case points, only the factor 5 remains, and you get 5M iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the worst-case complexity can be reduced below N×N, because it is possible to create input where no point is strictly less than any other point:

> For any value *n*, consider the plane that intersects with the Z, Y and Z axis at (n,0,0), (0,n,0) and (0,0,n), described by the equation *x+y+z=n*. If the input consists of points on such a plane, none of the points is strictly less than any other point.

Example of worst-case input:

```
(5,0,0) (4,1,0) (3,2,0) (2,3,0) (1,4,0) (0,5,0)  
(4,0,1) (3,1,1) (2,2,1) (1,3,1) (0,4,1)  
(3,0,2) (2,1,2) (1,2,2) (0,3,2)  
(2,0,3) (1,1,3) (0,2,3)  
(1,0,4) (0,1,4)  
(0,0,5)
```

However, the average complexity can be reduced to much less than N×N, e.g. with this approach:

- Take the first point from the input and put it in a list.
- Take the second point from the input, and compare it to the first
  point in the list. If it is strictly less, discard the new point. If
  it is strictly greater, replace the point in the list with the new
  point. If it is neither, add the point to the list.
- For each new point from the input, compare it to each point in the
  list. If it is stricly less than any point in the list, discard the
  new point. If it is strictly greater, replace the point in the list
  with the new point, and also discard any further points in the list
  which are strictly less than the new point. If the new point is not
  strictly less or greater than any point in the list, add the new
  point to the list.
- After checking every point in the input, the result is the number of
  points in the input minus the number of points in the list.

Since the probability that for any two random points *a* and *b* either a<b or b<a is 25%, the list won't grow to be very large (unless the input is specifically crafted to contain few or no points that are strictly less than any other point).

---

Limited testing with the code below (100 cases) with 1,000,000 randomly distributed points in a cubic space shows that the average list size is around 116 (with a maximum of 160), and the number of checks whether a point is strictly less than another point is around 1,333,000 (with a maximum of 2,150,000).

*(And a few tests with 10,000,000 points show that the average number of checks is around 11,000,000 with a list size around 150.)*

So in practice, the average complexity is close to N rather than N×N.

```js
function xyzLessCount(input) {
    var list = [input[0]];                                // put first point in list
    for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {              // check every point in input
        var append = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {           // against every point in list
            if (xyzLess(input[i], list[j])) {             // new point < list point
                append = false;
                break;                                    // continue with next point
            }
            if (xyzLess(list[j], input[i])) {             // new point > list point
                list[j] = input[i];                       // replace list point
                for (var k = list.length - 1; k > j; k--) {
                    if (xyzLess(list[k], list[j])) {      // check rest of list
                        list.splice(k, 1);                // remove list point
                    }
                }
                append = false;
                break;                                    // continue with next point
            }
        }
        if (append) list.push(input[i]);                  // append new point to list
    }
    return input.length - list.length;

    function xyzLess(a, b) {
        return a.x < b.x && a.y < b.y && a.z < b.z;
    }
}

var points = [];                                          // random test data
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    points.push({x: Math.random(), y: Math.random(), z: Math.random()});
}
document.write("1000000 &rarr; " + xyzLessCount(points));
```